# Can I get a pointer to a current iterator value

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

In my class I have two private members:

```
std::list<MyObject> objects;
MyObject *selecteObj;
```

When an event occurs I'd like to iterate through the list and run some sort of test that will only yield true on one of the items in the list. I'd like to save a pointer to that item for use elsewhere.

```
std::list<MyObject>::iterator i;
for (i = objects.begin(); i!=objects.end(); ++i){
    if (i->test())
        selectedObj = i;
}
```

Elsewhere In another method

```
if (selectedObj !=null)
    tmpObj->doSomething();
```

However this doesn't work because `i` isn't a pointer, its an iterator even though you can treat it like a pointer to an `MyObject`.

Is it possible to retrive the pointer that the iterator is storing internally for use elsewhere?

Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

What is the proper way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrive the pointer that the iterator is storing internally for use elsewhere?

Sure, just dereference the iterator with `*` and then get a pointer to the object via `&`:

```
selectedObj = &*i;
```

On a side note, did you remember to initialize `selectedObj` with `NULL` before the loop?

Comment: Surely you mean `std::addressof(*i)`, don't you? The OP didn't ask how to invoke the object's `&`-operator...

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think, you meant `std::addressof` (rather than `std::address_of`), don't you? :P

Comment: @Nawaz: oh, what did *I* say? ;-)

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to retrive the pointer that the iterator is storing internally for use elsewhere?

Yes. As @FredOverflow said, do this:

```
selectedObj = &*i;
```

However, if you can use features of C++11, then you can enjoy writing better syntax using *range-based* `for` loop as:

```
MyObject *selectedObj = NULL;
for (MyObject & obj : objects)
{
    if (obj.test())
        selectedObj = &obj; //store the address
}
```

Looks better? No need of iterator and writing syntax like `&*i`. It should be also noted that if the class `MyObject` has overloaded `operator &`, then `&*i` wouldn't work, as it would invoke the `operator&` function, instead of getting you the address of the object! If so, then you've write `(MyObject*)&(char&)*i` to get the address of `*i`, or in C++11 you can use `std::addressof(*i)` which you can define yourself if you cannot use C++11:

```
template< class T >
T* addressof(T& arg) {
    return (T*)&(char&)arg;
}
```

Code taken from here : [std::addressof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)